Overlay image comparison using Power BI Report Builder application
I want to create an overlay comparison of images in the Power BI Report Builder app.
First, I'd like to show you what my target image is :
Target image
Now the approach, that I was using to create it. I first started with removing backgrounds of the images, then creating public URL of these by uploading images to https://postimages.org/. After that I used these public URLs in may dataset then I was unable to find the graphical grid on Report Builder so I downloaded a grid image and when I used these to create overlay, I got 'Overlay I was able to create'image.

I want some reviews on how I can make it better?
Is there a way to use any graph to create a background grid including scales which shows us size comparison horizontally and vertically?

